# Upload CSV file that contains URLs in HTML page and read the URLs to be scrape using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, web-scraping, web

I'm currently need to make a web-based system that can upload a CSV file that contain list of URLs. After uploading, the system will read the URLs row by row and will be use for the next step which is scraping. Here, the scraping required to login to the website first then scraping. I already have the source code of login to the website. But, the problem is where I want to connect the html page named "upload_page.html" with the flask file named "upload_csv.py". Where should I put the source code of the login and scraping in the flask file?

upload_page.html

```
<div class="upload">
            <h2>Upload a CSV file</h2>
                <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                 <input type="file" name="file" accept=".csv">
                 <br>
                 <br>
                 <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                </form>
</div>
```

upload_csv.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import json
import time
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('upload_page.html')

#Code for Login to the website


@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    # Read the uploaded file
    csv_file = request.files['file']
    # Load the CSV data into a DataFrameSS
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    final_data = []
    # Loop over the rows in the DataFrame and scrape each link
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        link = row['Link']
        response = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        start = time.time()
        # will be used in the while loop
        initialScroll = 0
        finalScroll = 1000

        while True:
            driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo({initialScroll},{finalScroll})")
            # this command scrolls the window starting from the pixel value stored in the initialScroll
            # variable to the pixel value stored at the finalScroll variable
            initialScroll = finalScroll
            finalScroll += 1000

            # we will stop the script for 3 seconds so that the data can load
            time.sleep(2)
            end = time.time()
            # We will scroll for 20 seconds.
            if round(end - start) > 20:
                break

        src = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        # print(soup.prettify())

        #Code to do scrape the website

    return render_template('index.html', message='Scraped all data')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Is my coding for login and scrape is in the correct position? But, the coding is not working, where after I click the upload button, it is not being process

Answer (score -1):

```
csv_file = request.files['file']
# Load the CSV data into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
final_data = []
# Initialize the web driver
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
# Loop over the rows in the DataFrame and scrape each link
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    link = row['Link']
    # Login to the website
    # Replace this with your own login code
    driver.get("https://example.com/login")
    username_field = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
    password_field = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    username_field.send_keys("myusername")
    password_field.send_keys("mypassword")
    password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    # Wait for the login to complete
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_changes("https://example.com/login"))
    # Scrape the website
    driver.get(link)
    start = time.time()
    # will be used in the while loop
    initialScroll = 0
    finalScroll = 1000

    while True:
        driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo({initialScroll},{finalScroll})")
        # this command scrolls the window starting from the pixel value stored in the initialScroll
        # variable to the pixel value stored at the finalScroll variable
        initialScroll = finalScroll
        finalScroll += 1000

        # we will stop the script for 3 seconds so that the data can load
        time.sleep(2)
        end = time.time()
        # We will scroll for 20 seconds.
        if round(end - start) > 20:
            break
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).